# Why would my neural network give different values for the same input?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

It seems my neural network is outputting different values for a given input (e.g. xor 1,1)
The expected output of my neural network should be zero.  However, my net seems to be changing depending on what the random weights are, it sometimes will output a 0, other times a 1.  If I seed my random to a constant the number stays consistent.  The net converges toward 1 or 0 but it can't produce the correct output. Any reason as to why this could be?

Comment: Are you using a previously trained neural network, or are you rebuilding the neural network each time you are feeding the inputs?  I can't see why the output should change unless the configuration of the neural network has been adjusted.

Comment: What is your NN structure (number of layers & neurons per layer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XOR function is not trivial for a neural network. With a very few samples of training data you will be able to build OR function or AND functions. However, for XOR you may need more training data, more neurons, or more layers. If you are just testing your learning system, I suggest to start with a simple function like OR. If it works, then give it more training data and try to adjust the hyper-parameters (like the number of neurons) for learning an XOR function.